# Is it safe to send sensitive data in the post body to an azure function?

Tags: web-application, appsec, vulnerability

We want our users to send us a post request to an Azure Function endpoint. Is storing sensitive data (such as connectionstrings or passwords) in the post request body going to be an issue? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: doesn't seem like a good idea to post a connection string... what's the use case there?

Comment: How will the data be stored once received?

Comment: ```CURLOPT_SSLVERSION =>CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_DEFAULT``` - curl was compiled with TLS1.3? only accept 1.3. compiled with 1.4? only accept 1.4 and so on~

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Sending sensitive data in a post request is a common approach.** Take any form-based authentication mechanism for example. A user enters his credentials in the web-frontend (browser) and a post request is sent to the web-server in the backend. If this backend actually is a classical web application or an Azure function doesn't matter.

It is important though to **ensure transport security**. Using **HTTPS** (with TLS) **is state-of-the-art** in this regard. Appropriate algorithms, key-lengths and modes for your HTTPS configuration are defined in public standards and guidelines. I recommend the document [SOG-IS Crypto Evaluation Scheme Agreed Cryptographic Mechanisms](https://www.sogis.eu/documents/cc/crypto/SOGIS-Agreed-Cryptographic-Mechanisms-1.1.pdf) but there are others (with very similar recommendation). Depending on your location and/or your industrial sector, **there might be specific standards and guidelines** that are **required for compliance**.

One caveat in the end - **just because it is appropriate, doesn't mean it is the best option** you have. I do not know your actual requirements, so I cannot advise in this regard. That's something you have to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems based on the details provided, that the endpoint itself is not authenticated and the connection string is being sent in HTTP body. If this is indeed the case then:

**From transport point of view**, sending sensitive data in HTTP body might be **fine** as long as your connection is protected by HTTPS with TLSv1.2 or higher. Make sure clients are not ignoring certificate problems.

**From server security**, this could be susceptible to DDOS attack as your server endpoint will have to look at body in order to decide if this call is from a trusted client or a malicious user. Rate limiting in this case might also become very tough and will generally be a security issue.